# Prokon Paradiso Error

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, software

I am designing a simple structure using PROKON. The structure is a full 3D space frame. When I run the analysis I get an error called the Paradiso Error. This error only occurs when the structure is modeled in 3D however when a frame is modeled in 2D I do not get this error and the frame analysis can be completed.
I am wondering how to get rid of this error. Thanks
[image: The modeled structure in 3D]

[image: The paradiso error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zero-pivot error means your stiffness matrix has a zero element on the diagonal. This in turn is most likely caused by your structure containing (at least) one mechanism.

A good check would be to remove all releases at element joints and looking at the deformed shape. Another good idea is to change your pinned supports to fixed.

After you get the model to run you can re-apply joint releases and original supports a few at a time until you find what is generating your mechanism.